# Problem about Infimum

Tags: real-analysis

let $\sigma_j:=(\lfloor2^j(x)\rfloor+1)/2^j,$ where  $ x\geq 0 $.Then $\displaystyle\inf_{j \geq 1}\sigma_j=x;$?

Comment: This problem doesn't need as many variables as it has. Why not just replace $\eta-\tau$ with $x$ throughout, changing the condition $\eta\ge\tau,\,\eta,\,\tau\in\mathbb{R}^+$ to $x\ge 0$?

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite $x=\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +\{x\}$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. This fractional part then has a (possibly infinite) binary expansion $\{x\}=0.x_1x_2\dots$ The function $\sigma_j$ takes $x$, truncates this binary expansion at the $j^\mathrm{th}$ place, and adds one to the last digit. This always produces a number larger than $x$, but the error is bounded above by $2^{-j}$, which goes to zero as $j$ goes to infinity, so the infimum is $x$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$y-1<\lfloor y \rfloor \leq y\tag{1}$$  Substitute $y=2^jx$ in $(1)$and you'll easily solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help, from this last inequality replaced what you indicate as I guarantee that the x is the inf?